# error when calling job in another job pentaho web service

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a job like this, where a job calls another job, and for the path it uses variables, when run on local spoon, this job runs successfully,
[job in spoon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftSDR.png)

but when I upload it to the web service and create a schedule this job can't run and there is a notification like this
[job in web service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwk5N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time is this because of the case sensitivity of the underlying OS. We have it for example also between windows and linux machines. Try it with the filename in all lowercase. That is eitherway a good standard within Pentaho.

The other parts (asuming the files are in both situations in the same folder) should be fine.